# Javascript function with InnerHTML doesn't work

Tags: javascript, function, innerhtml

I'm trying to make a custom alert with javascript where in a function you put where do you want to redirect. This is what I have:

```
function CustomAlert(){
this.render = function(dialog, redirect){
var winW = window.innerWidth;
var winH = window.innerHeight;
var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
dialogbox.style.display = "block";

dialogbox.innerHTML = "<div id='dialogboxhead'><img src="/images/logo.png"></img></div> +
    "<div id='dialogboxbody'>" + dialog + "</div>" +
    "<div id='dialogboxfoot'><div class='alertokbtn'><button onclick='Alert.ok('" + redirect + "')'>OK</button></div></div>";

}
this.ok = function(redirect){
document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";

window.location = redirect;
}
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
```

This is what I'm establishing in HTML to run the function:

```
<div id="dialogoverlay"></div>
<div id="dialogbox">
  <div>
     <div id="dialogboxhead"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxbody"></div>
<div id="dialogboxfoot"></div>
</div>
</div>    

<button class="button" onClick="Alert.render('Alert test. This text can be anything by the way', 'https://google.com');" id="btn1">Get alert</button>
```

It opens the function with the text and everything, but when I press ok, it does not redirect me.

Comment: Paste your full code.

Comment: @SumonSarker That is legitimate my full code :p

Comment: `dialogoverlay`,`dialogbox` ID is missing

Comment: Oh well, yeah, nevermind. I forgot to paste that

Comment: The code you pasted has syntax errors, specifically unescaped quotes.

Comment: You have unescaped double-quotes in your double-quoted string that you are attempting to assign to the `innerHTML` property

Comment: The HTML you are generating for the OK button is not correct. It looks something like `<button onclick='Alert.ok('...')'>OK</button>`. Can you spot what is wrong? (if not, inspect the element in your browser).

Comment: `"<div id='dialogboxhead'><img src='/images/logo.png'></img></div>\
      <div id='dialogboxbody'>" + dialog + "</div>\
      <div id='dialogboxfoot'><div class='alertokbtn'><button onclick='Alert.ok('" + redirect + "')'>OK</button></div></div>"` The correct code for syntax error. @FranciscoF.

Comment: @SumonSarker: That still wouldn't generate the correct HTML.

Comment: Ahh! I see. I am making an answer for you. @FranciscoF.

Comment: I added an answer. @FranciscoF.

Comment: @SumonSarker I will get back to you tomorrow when I check it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code, You can try**

```js
function getObj(ID){
  return document.getElementById(ID);
}

function CustomAlert(){
  this.render = function(dialog, redirect){
 getObj('dialogoverlay').style.display = 'block';
 getObj('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
 getObj('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = "<button id=\"left\" onclick=\"Alert.ok('"+redirect+"')\">OK</button> <button id=\"right\" onclick=\"Alert.close()\">Close</button>";
  }
  this.ok = function(redirect){
 window.location = redirect;
  }

  this.close = function(){
 getObj('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
  }
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#dialogoverlay{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#dialogbox{
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
#dialogboxhead img{
  width: 100px;
  margin: 30px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#dialogboxfoot{
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  padding: 5px;
}
#left{
  float: left;
}
#right{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="dialogoverlay">
  <div id="dialogbox">
    <div>
      <div id="dialogboxhead">
        <img src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Google"/>
      </div>
      <p id="dialogboxbody"></p>
      <div id="dialogboxfoot"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="button" onClick="Alert.render('Alert test. This text can be anything by the way', 'https://google.com');" id="btn1">Get alert</button>
```

> **Note**: Use this code to your script. Because, In Snippet `window.location` function will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```js
function CustomAlert(){
  this.render = function(dialog, redirect){
    var winW = window.innerWidth;
    var winH = window.innerHeight;
    var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
    var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
    dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
    dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
    dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
    dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
    dialogbox.style.display = "block";

    dialogbox.innerHTML = `<div id='dialogboxhead'><img src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Google"></img></div>
        <div id='dialogboxbody'>${dialog}</div>
        <div id='dialogboxfoot'><div class='alertokbtn'><button onclick='Alert.ok("${redirect}")'>OK</button></div></div>`;

    }
    this.ok = function(redirect){
    document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";

    window.location = redirect;
  }
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
```

```html
<div id="dialogoverlay">
  <div id="dialogbox">
    <div id="dialogboxhead"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxbody"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxfoot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
   
<button class="button" onClick="Alert.render('Alert test. This text can be anything by the way', 'https://google.com');" id="btn1">Get alert</button>
```